# Android NDK : make: *** No rule to make target. Stop

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libusb, libusb-1.0

I am trying to build [libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/libusb) using the NDK. Here is my `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` I have checked this thread [Android NDK: No rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target) but it didn't work for me.

Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libusb
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libusb/core.c libusb/descriptor.c libusb/io.c libusb/sync.c libusb/os/linux_usbfs.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI:= all
APP_LDFLAGS:= -llog
APP_STL:= stlport_shared
APP_CPP_FEATURES:= exceptions
APP_PLATFORM:= android-21
APP_CFLAGS:= -g
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.williams.libusbpoc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

local.properties

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\android-ndk-r15
```

Project structure looks like below:

[image]

When I am running `ndk-build` then I get

```
ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-21 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 1 in D:/williams/android/libusbpoc/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be comptible with devices older than android-21. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.
make: *** No rule to make target `C:/android-ndk-r15/build//../sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libusb/core.c', needed by `D:/williams/android/libusbpoc/app/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/usb/libusb/core.o'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set `LOCAL_PATH`, i.e. in your `Android.mk` you should have:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#  ..etc as before..
```